# unable to pass spuser as paramter into CAML query

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, caml-query, spuser

I want to pass the spuser as a paramter to the caml query

but when i tried the below code its throwing error:

```
        using (SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPDocumentLibrary objDocLibProjDocLibrary = 
         spWeb.Lists.TryGetList("ProjectDocumentLibrary") as 
       SPDocumentLibrary;

                   // string strsingleProjCodeStageTupleSet = 
          "VGIL_NPR_TBD_STB_050_2017"; 
         //"VGIL_NPR_EMD_STB_993_2017";//"VGIL_NPR_EMD_STB_999_2017"; 

                    string strstage1 = "Concept And Design Proto 
          Developement";//"Feasibility and Kick Off"; //
                    string strnp11user =@"mydomain\NPD11";


                    string strsingleProjCodeforptp = 
           "VGIL_NPR_TBD_STB_050_2017";
                    SPUser objuser1 = spWeb.EnsureUser(strnp11user);

                    //objuser1.LoginName

                   string  strPTPQueryforPDL = "<Where><And><Eq>"
                         + "<FieldRef Name='ProjectCode' />"
           Value Type='Text'>" + strsingleProjCodeforptp + "</Value>"
                        + "</Eq><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='AssignedTo' />"
                       + "<Value Type='User'>" + objuser1.LoginName + "
        </Value></Eq><Or><IsNull>"
                       + "<FieldRef Name='TriggerFromTimerJob' />"
                       + "</IsNull><Eq>"
                       + "<FieldRef Name='TriggerFromTimerJob' /><Value 
          Type='Text'>NO</Value>"
                       + "</Eq></Or></And></And></Where>";
                    SPQuery oQueryProjDocLibCodeStage = new SPQuery();
                    SPListItemCollection 
              oListItemCollProjDocLibProjCodeStage;
                    oQueryProjDocLibCodeStage.Query = strPTPQueryforPDL;
                    oListItemCollProjDocLibProjCodeStage = 
       objDocLibProjDocLibrary.GetItems(oQueryProjDocLibCodeStage);

                    int counterprojdoclibstage = 
       oListItemCollProjDocLibProjCodeStage.Count;

        if (oListItemCollProjDocLibProjCodeStage != null && 
       oListItemCollProjDocLibProjCodeStage.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (SPListItem singleProjDocLibCodeStageItem in 
            oListItemCollProjDocLibProjCodeStage)
                        {
                            int idofmatchingprojdoclib = 
           Convert.ToInt32(singleProjDocLibCodeStageItem["ID"]);

                        }
                    }
```

it seems ,  ""
                           + "" + objuser1.LoginName + "" line of query is throwing error.

in order to get the correct items after caml query execution, what should be written ? i cant hardcode the spuser values

am using NTLM authentication .
 i tried with the below query as well:

```
     string  strPTPQueryforPDL = "<Where><And><Eq>"
                         + "<FieldRef Name='ProjectCode' />"
                        + "<Value Type='Text'>" + strsingleProjCodeforptp + 
                  "</Value>"
                        + "</Eq><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='AssignedTo' />"
                       + "<Value Type='Integer'><UserID>" + objuser1.ID + "
                 </UserID></Value></Eq><Or><IsNull>"
                       + "<FieldRef Name='TriggerFromTimerJob' />"
                       + "</IsNull><Eq>"
                       + "<FieldRef Name='TriggerFromTimerJob' /><Value  
           Type='Text'>NO</Value>"
                       + "</Eq></Or></And></And></Where>";

                   that also failed!
```

```
            <Eq><FieldRef Name='AssignedTo' />"
      + "<Value Type='User' LookupId='True'>>" + objuser1.Id+ "</Value></Eq>
```

also didnt work
Which one is the correct caml query to get the actual result count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to add  LookupId="True" for the field in CAML Query,

```
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo" LookupId="True" />
    <Value Type="User">//userid here ex. objuser1.Id</Value>
  </Eq>
```

By following ways you can make query on user,

- **If you know the display name of the user**

  ```
  <Where>
   <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name='User_x0020_ID' />
     <Value Type='User'>System Account</Value>
  </Eq>
  </Where>
  ```
- **If you know the User Id ( not the login id)**

  ```
    <Where>
      <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name='User_x0020_ID' LookupId='True'  />
      <Value Type='User'>1073741823</Value>
      </Eq>
   </Where>
  ```
- **If you would like to filter based on current user (logged in User )**

  ```
   <Where>
   <Eq>
     <FieldRef Name='User_x0020_ID'/>
     <Value Type='User'><UserID/></Value>
  </Eq>
  </Where>
  ```

you can visit [this](http://www.ashokraja.me/tips/How-to-use-User-Name-User-Id-Logged-in-User-Id-in-SharePoint-CAML-Query).

Answer (score 0):

try like this
Instead of  1 pass the userid

```
 <Where>
     <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name='User' LookupId='TRUE' />
       <Value Type='Lookup'>1</Value>
     </Eq>
    </Where>
```